# Hot to create a zip file with Play! Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, zip

I have a bunch of public assets that I would like to zip and provide for download.

Is there an easy way in Play! to create a zip for a list of files/folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can always use Java libraries. See [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) for details

Answer (score 0):

`play war "project_dir" -o "war_file_name" --zip`

Note: I'm using Play-1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use Play helper class, Files.zip

Answer (score 0):

In the controller use this:

```
public class Public extends Controller {
  public static void download() {
    File dir = VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("/dir-to-zip/").getRealFile();
    File zip = VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("/files.zip").getRealFile();
    Files.zip(dir, zip);
    renderBinary(zip);
  }
}
```

Then add this to your routes file:

```
*        /download                 Public.download
```

Note that file paths are from your application root, not your file system root.