# Play 2.4.x -- how to create a zip file download of several private assets

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, zip

Please note this is NOT a duplicate of this question: [Hot to create a zip file with Play! Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546565/hot-to-create-a-zip-file-with-play-framework)

What I'm asking is to assemble a series of (**private**) assets -- some of which may be static files but more importantly ***some of which will be XML files generated with @twirl***.

I do see the Java libraries and I've done things like that before and I could see perhaps having the Java libraries call those assets by URL (somehow passing or bypassing security) and then subsequently assembling all those files into a master ZIP file but I have to believe that there would/should be a far, far more elegant way to do this using something like the Promises/Futures structure? (Much like the main page of LinkedIN is done with live assembling of the various components from numerous resources).

Anyone have any ideas?